# WSO2 /token resource not found

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to get a token to use in a call to a service published through WSO2 API Gateway and for that I'm calling the /token resource on https://:8243/token with a POST method and "grant_type=client credentials" and the correct Authorization header but the server returns 404 resource /token not available
If I use the Curl call generated using the "store" application I get the same error.

If I use the resource through the carbon application everything works though, I make the call to https://:9443/oauth2/token and I get the token back
Could anybody help me getting the application on the 8243 port to work?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

apimanger serves https api  calls in port 8243 and http api call in port 8280 and it is defined under transportReceiver in the axis2.xml /repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml).

Even though it is listening 8243 , if that port is not opened to outside from your server, then you will not be able to access via port 8243.So
 Check whether port 8243 is opened in your server where apimanger gateway runs .You can use telnet command and check whether you are able to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if in < APIM > /repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api you find the _ TokenAPI _ .xml 
I had the same issue and found the file renamed with .back. Removing the .back extension and restarting the server worked.

Comment: Indeed this solution worked for me. But, I would like to understand why we need to do this change and is it possible that WSO2 will rename the files with .back extension file any time in the future?